# How enable PHPFOX v4.0 extensions section

Tags: module, phpfox

I wonder if you tell me how i can enable phpfox v4.5 extensions section to add new module to phpfox!
I am using phpfox v4.5 nulled and i'm trying to write new module for that, but unfortunately i can not find extension section like before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHPFOX v4.x there is disable extension from the admincp. But you can create custom app which is like module by refer below link.

https://docs.phpfox.com/display/FOX4DEVDOC/Writing+Your+First+App

Follow the steps and first enable techie mode which link given on above link.